# What are the advantages/disadvantages of using a SubmitField from flask wtforms vs a html submit button?

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms

I am creating Login, Signup, and a few other forms which require the user to click on a submit button. What is the difference between using a `SubmitField` in my form class vs using html `<input type="submit" value="Log in">` ? Which should I prefer and when?

I initially created with html because I was unaware of the `SubmitField` option in wtforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WTForms SubmitField will create required HTML code ( field value, name, label etc.. ) ( you can apply styles also ). In your HTML, you've to write all these.

You can use any of these. It all comes to how you're getting data from form and processing it in the backend.